# Is it possible to detect that the IE8 debugger is attached

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

I have some code in my application that wraps function.apply and function.call in try/catch blocks. It's handy for catching errors and building up a pseudo-stack using arguments.caller but it plays havoc with IE's debugger.

I can turn off the wrapping with a url parameter but I'd like to turn it off automatically if the debugger is attached. I can't find a way to detect the debugger. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it give you objects like firebugs and chromes `console`? In that case, `if (console)` and a check that determines whether the browser is IE should be sufficient.

Comment: @thejh I wish that were the case. console appears when the debugger is open but not attached. I really need to know when it is attached.

Comment: does the debugger react on catched exceptions in some way?

Comment: @thejh The problem is that it won't break on errors if they were caught by try/catch. I end up removing my try/catch block manually to reproduce the error so I can get it to break on the error. Obviously this isn't too nice when the error happens only in a production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer you wanted, but I've handled this in the past by having a small bit of loader JS that begins by checking the hash, if any, in the URL, for a secret code, like:

mysite.com/#mXVa

So the loader checks and if location.hash == 'mXVa', my loader loads the debug versions of all the scripts on the page (no try/catch, etc) rather than the minified, error-eating variety.

Comment: Yeah, I have something similar set up now. It seems like the only way :(

Answer (score 2):

Not sure for IE8, but you can detect if the debugger is running in IE9/IE10/IE11 by checking:

```
var isIeDebugging = !!window.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_COMMAND_LINE || ('__BROWSERTOOLS_DOMEXPLORER_ADDED' in window);
```

e.g. see http://jsbin.com/IJOwuje/5

However, in IE9/IE10 this is set to true for a window that has run the debugger just once, even if the debugger now closed.

Also in IE11 the various window.__BROWSERTOOLS* keys seem to only appear depending upon which debugger tab is open or used, so not 100% reliable for checking if the debugging frame is open...